# Visual Studio gives me suggestions for IDE0050, but selecting its solution causes a compiler error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 targeting .NET 5.0 with Entity Framework Core, I'm getting an annoying code suggestion for the code below when I declare a key on multiple fields.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntityType>()
      .HasKey(k => new { k.KeyField1, k.KeyField2 });
}
```

I get the following suggestion on that line:  `IDE0050: Convert to tuple`

If I select the Convert to Tuple action, Visual Studio changes my code to

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntityType>()
      .HasKey(k => (k.KeyField1, k.KeyField2));
}
```

And now I have the error `CS8143: An expression tree may not contain a tuple literal.`

Is there a way to disable Visual Studio's suggestion on that line, or is there a correct change to my code that will satisfy Visual Studio?

I tried putting the line `dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0050.severity = none` in my .editorconfig file, but that doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that advice is bad advice as the analyzer does not take into account *why* you want to create an object/type in the first place. You should revert to the original code and then ask code analysis to ignore that suggestion.

Comment: See [dotnet/roslyn#50468](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/50468). Looks like that one altered in Jan this year -- are you running a new-ish Visual Studio version?

Comment: Also, code suggestions are just suggestions. You can (and often should) ignore them.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen When I click on the little light bulb icon, it doesn't give me any options to ignore this suggestion.  I would love to ignore it and have Visual Studio stop marking that line.

Comment: @canton7 Yes, I'm running the most recent update to 2019 (16.11.5).

Comment: You should go ask what the status of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69760242/visual-studio-gives-me-suggestions-for-ide0050-but-selecting-its-solution-cause) is because this seems to have been flagged as fixed, but your description indicates it hasn't.